# GEE Classification Error Multiple Geometry types

Tags: google-earth-engine, polygon, geometry, image-classification

I came to the issue of Out of Memory Error when I tried to do a supervised classification of an image using a shapefile polygons as underlying featureCollection in GEE.
It turned out that some of the polygons that I used for sampling the underlying pixels are due to some reason not of "polygon" type but of "GeometryCollection" type (mostly combination of polygon and LineString). I wonder if it is possible to correct these non-polygons and correct their geometry type into "polygon" without producing other side effects?

[image]

Please see the attached image of one 'bad' geometry example. This should be a "Polygon" but it has a sliver in it which turned the polygon into "GeometryCollection" consisting of a 'Polygon' + 'LineString'. Unfortunately about one-third of my featureCollection is populated with such geometries! I need to somehow get rid of these artifacts.

Comment: The question is really invariant to the code. It is rather related to optimal handling of a featureCollection in GEE.  Just imagine that I have a featureCollection with 2 features. The geometry of  feature_1 is of type "Polygon" and the geometry of feature_2 is of type "GeometryCollection". The question is that, is it possible to turn the GeometryCollection into a Polygon or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the polygon within the GeometryCollection using (if there is one):

```
var list = geometryCollection.geometries().filter(ee.Filter.hasType('item','Polygon'))
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon(ee.Geometry(list.get(0)).coordinates())
```

or a multi polygon if the collection has multiple polygons:

```
var list = geometryCollection.geometries().filter(ee.Filter.hasType('item','Polygon'))
var multiPolygon = ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(list)
```

Comment: Thanks @Kadir Şahbaz. Yes "Filter.hasType"  returns the right geometry (in my case Polygon) . I need to take one more step and replace this geometry (polygon) with the old one (GeometryCollection). I think I need to use Feature.setGeometry(). however this gives me an error !